# why the sympy.solve does not return any solution?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to solve below equation using sympy.solve

```
import sympy as sp

theta = sp.symbols('theta')
x = 0

eq = sp.cos(theta)**2 - sp.sin(theta)**2 - sp.sin(theta)*sp.sqrt(sp.sin(theta)**2 + x) + sp.sin(theta)*sp.cos(theta)**2 / sp.sqrt(sp.sin(theta)**2 + x)

soln = sp.solve(eq, theta)

print(soln)
```

Actually, if x = 0, eq will be `cos^2(theta) - sin^2(theta)` and the solutions are pi/4, 3pi/4, ... .
But, above code does not return any number, only `[]` return.
If x is not 0, this code does work.
Why this code return `[]` when x = 0?

Comment: How does it simplify to `cos^2(theta) - sin^2(theta)`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly why `solve` does not work in this case, but `solveset` seems to work better. The [docs](http://lidavidm.github.io/sympy/modules/solvers/solveset.html) suggest that there is an assumption of the domain being made, which defaults to Complex numbers when `solveset` is used.

```py
import sympy as sp

theta = sp.Symbol('theta', real=False)
x = 0.0

eq = sp.cos(theta)**2 - sp.sin(theta)**2 - sp.sin(theta)*sp.sqrt(sp.sin(theta)**2 + x) + sp.sin(theta)*sp.cos(theta)**2 / sp.sqrt(sp.sin(theta)**2 + x)

soln = sp.solveset(eq, theta)
```

Resulting `soln`:

$\displaystyle \left{2 n \pi + \frac{5 \pi}{4}; |; n \in \mathbb{Z}\right} \cup \left{2 n \pi + \frac{3 \pi}{4}; |; n \in \mathbb{Z}\right} \cup \left{2 n \pi + \frac{7 \pi}{4}; |; n \in \mathbb{Z}\right} \cup \left{2 n \pi + \frac{\pi}{4}; |; n \in \mathbb{Z}\right}$

[image]